# Align img element in the middle

Tags: html, css

I need to set image in the middle of the element.

Example of my CSS:

```
.main {
    width: 600px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 100px -300px;
    background-color: green;
}
.main .image-holder {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
.main .image-holder img {
    margin: 10px auto;
}
```

`.main` has fixed width, but also that size is dynamically changable in the jQuery.

`.image-hodler` should be something like a thumbnail. I set width to the 100% because, I never know, what size will main element have.

`img` and here that `margin` setted as `auto` doesn't work.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bj6meje0/)

Comment: is this what you need? http://jsfiddle.net/bj6meje0/3/

Comment: Actually yes, but it is better to me to not use positions on inner elements. When I will add something in the future, it would messed my styles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add 'text-align:  center' on the parent div, like so : http://jsfiddle.net/bj6meje0/1/

```
.main .image-holder {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    text-align: center
}
```

Or you can change the image behavior to display as block, in html the image is like an 'character' so you can do:

```
.main .image-holder img {
    display: block;
    margin: 10px auto;
}
```

**Fiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/bj6meje0/2/

The difference? With the second aproch you will be able to change the "text-align" property of the div, otherwise the text will appear centered as the picture

Comment: Why I didn't think about this before... Thanks.

Comment: @debute : because simple answers are most difficult ones to think these days!! :)

Comment: Probably I should go to the vacation somewhere.

Comment: Of coruse I can, but I need to wait 15 minutes until the question was posted.

Comment: Ok :D Right...I'd forgotten about the delay